# Why `std::string str(nullptr)` and `std::string str=nullptr` is wrong? Could someone explain the reasons in details?

Tags: c++, string

Why `std::string str(nullptr)` and `std::string str=nullptr` is wrong? Could someone explain the reasons in details?

Comment: Because both yield undefined behaviour.    The constructor called for the first and the assignment operator called for the second both assume they are passed a non-null pointer  (that points the the first character of a nul-terminated array of `char`).

Comment: Use `""` to assign an empty string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such examples compile because there exists a `std::string(const char*)` constructor for accepting null-terminated strings, which is the standard version of storing strings in C. Also, arrays eagerly decay into pointers, in order to allow code such as `std::string("Ahoj")` to compile.

It is wrong because the constructor expects a valid null-terminated string, although your example compiles, its behaviour is undefined.

Similarly `std::string str(0);` will work and is undefined too because the literal zero is implicitly convertible to a pointer as it was used as pre-C++11 version of `nullptr` - `NULL`.

C++23 fixed this by [adding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) `basic_string( std::nullptr_t ) = delete;` constructor, making all examples with `nullptr` or `0` compile-time errors.

**EDIT:**
I originally claimed `std::logic_error` will be thrown, @François Andrieux corrected me.

Comment: It is Undefined Behavior. It may throw `std::logic_error` if the implementation chooses to handle that case, but it might not.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, I hate how much is left undefined when you have perfectly capable RAII of handling this.

Answer (score 4):

When you write `std::string str`, you're declaring a string. `nullptr` is a [pointer value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

So if you had a string *pointer*, you could do this `std::string *str(nullptr);`.

But with just a straight `std::string` it makes no sense.

---

I'm guessing you're coming from Java or C# where all objects behind the scenes are secretly pointers/references. So when you write `String str`, you would initialize it to `null` (or the language's equivalent). But in C++, nothing is a pointer unless you explicitly declare it to be so (which you shouldn't unless you know you *really* need a pointer).

What that means, is that an `std::string` (like an `int` or `std::vector` or ...) in C++ will *always* have a value.

Comment: But you see `std::string str("")` works. It passes a pointer to the ctor indeed. It really confuses me.

Comment: @John `""` (the empty string) is still *a string*. `null` or `nullptr` means there is no object there at all.

Comment: It's incorrect but it is not a compilation error. It will try to read the null terminated string pointed to by the pointer, which will be dereferencing null.

Comment: @scohe001 "null or nullptr means there is no object there at all." No, in the current case it means there is a valid string at address 0. If it means nullptr is "no string" it must be defined that way but is is not!

Comment: @Klaus you're correct that with the way OP has written it, C++ interprets the code like you say (and Quimby's answer goes more in-depth on that). But I'm trying to correct the misconception that I'm guessing OP has from working in other OOP languages. I'm operating on the assumption that when they write `std::string str = nullptr`, they are trying to store `nullptr` (a lack of any string object) in `str` like you would in C#/Java/etc.

Comment: @scohe001 One extra question, what is "OP" short for? It's often seen on StackOverflow. But I can't find the right meaning for it on https://www.abbreviations.com/OP.